# Crossing Schengen: port of entry for residency permit holders?

Tags: resident-permit, schengen

I have the Red White Red Card (residency card) from Austria. I am flying to the outside of Schengen, and my port of entry back to Schengen is Milan, Italy then back to Vienna as there are no reasonably priced direct flights to Vienna.

Will I be denied entry to Schengen?

Comment: No. Your passport and residence card together fulfill the needed entry conditions to the Schengen Area.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, does this mean that I need a direct flight to Austria?

Comment: No, you may enter through any Schengen Country.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, thank you for your clarifcation. If you please, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will I be denied entry to Schengen?

No. Your passport and residence card together fulfill the needed entry conditions to the Schengen Area and you may enter through any Schengen Country.

Outside of Austria the 90/180 days rule applies (but is not strickly enforced).